# why is it wrong to say the children go to school on foot

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-usage

I am visiting a small village in China.
There is a kindergarten near the small village.
Every morning, the children in the village walk to the kindergarten.
I don't get it why my professor says it is definitely wrong to say this,

> the children go to school on foot.

Comment: You should ask your professor for an explanation, because I'm stumped.

Comment: It is definitely understandable. Is he saying it should be "by foot" or simply "walk to school"? Why is it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Normally we would simply say

> The children walk to school.

The phrase **on foot** is typically used to draw attention to the fact that some other mode of locomotion was not used or could not be used:

> We drove into the jungle in our 4x4 vehicles, but we had to abandon
>   them and proceed *on foot* when the dirt road ended. The vegetation was
>   nearly impenetrable.

It is possible that your context could support the use. For example:

> The school bus gathers children from the surrounding villages and
>   brings them to the school parking lot. But the school is perched high up on a
>   hill, overlooking the valley, and the children must go the final quarter mile on foot.

Comment: So, is "going to school on foot" `definitely wrong `, as suggested by the OP's teacher, or not? Because that is the crux of the question.

Comment: I think the crux of the question is  "How to use the collocation **on foot**?"  If you think the crux of the question is "Was my teacher wrong?" then feel free to answer it.

Comment: The OP didn't ask "how" to use the idiom **on foot**, I'm merely pointing it out. Feel free to ignore the clarification.

Comment: I do, and will.

Answer (score -3):

You can say: "The children go to school by walking. "

Comment: This is grammatical but **by walking** is not truly idiomatic. We would not say "I went to school by walking" but "I walked to school".

Comment: Ohh, but it's grammatically correct, isn't it?

Comment: Grammatically correct it is.

Comment: Ok, I have just learnt something more :D